# Nativescript-vue overflow visible for absolute positioned element outside bounds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm fairly new to Nativescript and I'm woring on my first android app, I want to have the child of my AbsoluteLayout to be visible outside its parent's bounds, currently it's not showing outside bounds.

```
<AbsoluteLayout style="width:100%; height:20px; background-color:yellow; z-index:9999999;">
    <Label :text="'fa-star' | fonticon" top="-15px" left="200px" 
           class="fa c_primary fs_small" style="z-index:9999;">
    </Label>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Is there a way to set overflow:visible in Nativescript?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `setClipChildren(false);` on the parent layout. If `AbsoluteLayout` is on your `Page` then you should call this method on the native view of page.

For example in page loaded event,

```
   <Page @loaded="loaded">

    ....

    methods: {
        loaded: function(args){
            args.object.android.setClipChildren(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked for me, if you have issues please share a Playground sample.